# Add more data when tableview reached end

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I am getting some data from server using `Alamofire` like this :

```
func getNewestFeed(order:String , page:Int)  {
        Alamofire.request("https://blahblah.com/api/front/\(page)/\(order)", method: .post, parameters: ["foo":"bar"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON(completionHandler: { respone in

            if respone.response?.statusCode == 200 {

                let result = respone.result.value as! [String:Any]
                self.newestArray = result["records"] as! [Any]
                self.tableView.reloadData()


            } else {
                //Show error
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation { self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) }
            }

        })
    }
```

by default server gives me page 1, now I need to add more data too `self.newestArray` to load more contents. So here is the code :

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let lastElement = newestArray.count - 1

        if indexPath.row == lastElement {

            //add more data 
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to add `result` to  `self.newestArray` , like this :

```
let result = respone.result.value as! [String:Any]  
                self.newestArray.append(result["records"] as! [Any])
                self.tableView.reloadData()
```

but crashes with this error :

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array' (0x109c3c828) to
>   'Swift.Dictionary' (0x109c3c798).

How should I addd more array to `self.newestArray` and show it again in table view ?

Comment: The parameter type of `append` is a **single** object. There is also a method which takes an **array** of objects. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append(_:)` is used to add a **single** element to the end of the array.
There is [`append(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2854129-append) if you want to add a collection of items:

```
self.newestArray.append(contentsOf: result["records"] as! [Any])
```